# How can I prevent a mount from being displayed as a removable media?

Tags: nautilus, mount

When a user session starts, I bind some /mnt/nfs_share into /home/username/afolder using mount --bind. Then Nautilus displays the mounted folder as a separate volume and the removable media applet is shown to allow ejection. I would like the binding to be transparent for the user.

Using a symbolic link isn't exactly what I'm looking for, because the user can delete this link from its home directory and the folder appears as external to user home tree.

Comment: Are you doing it in the command line or in fstab?

Answer (score 0):

I am mounting the nfs shares in my dormitory with this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Comment: I've tried to mount /home/auser/nfs_share using autofs, but it still appears as a removable media :-(

Comment: Sorry. I used fedora, and in my setup, the mountpoints were written in fstab. I didn't knew ubuntu acted differently.